# ¿Cómo funciona max() en python con strings?

Tags: python

Este el el código:

```
 a='alv'

 b='jja'

 max(a,b)
```

El resultado es ***'jja'***.

Comment: Desconozco python, pero si te fijas, 'jja' empieza con 'j', y 'alv' con 'a'. En el abecedario la 'j' va después de la 'a', por lo tanto, supongo que por eso la pone como máxima (o mayor).

Comment: @Luis precisamente es como lo comentas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa la documentación:

> [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) Devuelva el elemento más grande en un iterable o el mayor
>   conviertiendo el caracter a su valor ASCII
>   de dos o más argumentos. Si se proporciona un argumento posicional,
>   debería ser un iterable. Se devuelve el artículo más grande en el
>   iterable. Si se proporcionan dos o más argumentos posicionales, se
>   devuelve el mayor de los argumentos posicionales.

Creo que con este ejemplo se puede entender mejor:

```
valor1='w'
valor2='a'
valor3='z'
valor4='b'  
valor5='c'  

max(valor1,valor2,valor3,valor4,valor5)
print(ord(valor3)) # ascii convert 
print(ord(valor2)) # ascii convert
```

la salida sería:

`z`
`122`
`97`

Te sugiero revisar:
[**Comparisons**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

Los objetos de diferentes tipos, excepto los números, están ordenados por sus nombres de tipo; los objetos del mismo tipo que no admiten una comparación adecuada se ordenan por su dirección.

Comment: He modificado el ejemplo :-). si deseas podrías agregar uno por favor.

Comment: El último parrafo es incorrecto. Para poder ordenar o encontrar máximo o mínimo entre varios objetos, todos deben implementar ciertos métodos que permitan ordenarlos o compararlos. La comparación entre elementos de distinto tipo también debe estar definida por los tipos en cuestión (o al menos por uno de ellos). No se ordenan por su nombre de tipo ni por su id. `max([1,2], "hola", {"a": 5})` da error.

Comment: ¿En verdad?, es de la documentación :-.

Comment: Curioso... pues acabo de verificarlo. Igual era así en python2?

Comment: Python3: _Objects of different types, except different numeric types, never compare equal. Furthermore, some types (for example, function objects) support only a degenerate notion of comparison where any two objects of that type are unequal. The <, <=, > and >= operators will raise a TypeError exception when comparing a complex number with another built-in numeric type, when the objects are of different types that cannot be compared, or in other cases where there is no defined ordering._

Comment: Python2: _Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array yields a consistent result). Furthermore, some types (for example, file objects) support only a degenerate notion of comparison where any two objects of that type are unequal. Again, such objects are ordered arbitrarily but consistently. The <, <=, > and >= operators will raise a TypeError exception when any operand is a complex number._

Answer (score 0):

Aunque las respuestas que has recibido son perfectas, creo que una pequeña aclaración puede ser útil para quien dé con esta respuesta buscando información sobre la función `max()`.

Simplemente indicar que lo que hace `max()` no depende del tipo de datos que le pases como parámetro. Conceptualmente podemos comprender lo que hace si imaginamos que ordena de menor a mayor la lista (o los argumentos) que reciba como parámetro, y después se queda con el último elemento.

Tanto `max()`, como `min()`, como `sorted()` pueden recibir un parámetro iterable (por ejemplo una lista), bien una serie de parámetros separados por comas. Los elementos del iterable (o los parámetros separados por comas) son los que comparará entre sí de cara a ordenarlos.

Es necesario que la operación de comparación esté definida para los tipos que va a ordenar. En el caso de números la copmaración está clara. En el caso de cadenas, la ordenación es alfabética. En otros casos depende de cómo lo defina el tipo el tipo en cuestión.

A la función `max()`, al igual que a la función `sorted()` se le puede pasar un parámetro `key` que sirve para definir tu propio critero de ordenación en caso de que el tipo a ordenar carezca de uno, o quieras implementar una ordenación diferente.

Cuando el campo `key` está presente, ha de ser una función (o más generalmente, un *callable*, que es cualquier objeto python que se pueda llamar). En ese caso `max()` (o `sorted()`) invocará a la función especificada por `key` pasándole como parámetro cada elemento a ordenar y la ordenación se hará *en base al valor retornado* por `key`.

Por ejemplo, imagina que tus cadenas tienen esta forma:

```
data= [ "Madrid, España", 
        "Bototá, Colombia",
        "Barcelona, España",
        "Berna, Suiza",
        "París, Francia",
        "Burdeos, Francia",
        "Buenos Aires, Argentina",
        "Córdoba, Argentina"
       ]
```

Si las ordenas usando `sorted(nombres)`, se ordenarían alfabéticamente, siendo la primera `'Barcelona, España'` y la última `'París, Francia'` (esos serían por tanto los valores retornados por `min(data)` y `max(data)`, respectivamente.

Pero ¿y si queremos que se ordenen por su país,  y dentro de cada país alfabéticamente por el nombre de la ciudad? Aquí es donde el parámetro `key` es util, al permitirnos transformar cada dato de entrada en otro que será el usado para la ordenación.

Por ejemplo, podemos partir la cadena en la coma, y "dar la vuelta" a la tupla resultante:

```
def pais_primero(cadena):
    return cadena.split(",")[::-1]
```

(lo de `[::-1]` es un "truco pythonico" para devolver una lista en orden inverso)

Con esta función como `key`, cada cadena de entrada se convierte en una lista en la salida. Las listas tienen definido un criterio de ordención por defecto, que consiste en ordenarlas según el valor de su primer elemento, y si éstos son iguales, según el valor del segundo, etc. Por tanto es lo que queríamos.

Con este criterio vemos:

```
>>> sorted(data, key=pais_primero)
['Buenos Aires, Argentina',
 'Córdoba, Argentina',
 'Bototá, Colombia',
 'Barcelona, España',
 'Madrid, España',
 'Burdeos, Francia',
 'París, Francia',
 'Berna, Suiza']
```

Por lo que `max(data)` sería ahora `Berna, Suiza`.